# Check if two List<E> have some single common element

Tags: java, list, contains

I am trying to check if two lists have some single common element. I have tried different ways but it always return false. By now I am using the method contains(Object):

```
private void setImportedAreaParameters(EList<EArea> exitingAreas) {
    EList<EPoint> importedAreaPoints = importedArea.getPoly().getPoints();
    for (EArea existingArea : exitingAreas){
        EList<EPoint> existingAreaPoints = existingArea.getPoly().getPoints();
        if(importedAreaPoints.contains(existingAreaPoints)){
            importedArea.setImportChoice(EImportAreaChoiceEnum.REPLACE);
        }
        else if (importedAreaPoints.size() >= POLYGON_POINTS_MAX_VALUE){
            importedArea.setImportChoice(EImportAreaChoiceEnum.TO_MANY_POINT);
        }
    }
}
```

The EList importedAreaPoints and existingAreaPoints have exactly the same elements.

importedAreaPoints 
`[com.samu.domain.EPoint@45f5fd38 (lat: -5.580874037404866, lon: 35.94777225005756), com.samu.domain.EPoint@3dd4c25c (lat: -5.286985080169555, lon: 35.97486383222591), com.samu.domain.EPoint@18a80682 (lat: -5.286985080169555, lon: 35.71115171259456), com.samu.domain.EPoint@6c992dd3 (lat: -5.573099299909384, lon: 35.68508505352236), com.samu.domain.EPoint@6ef0145 (lat: -5.580874037404866, lon: 35.94777225005756)]`

existingAreaPoints 
`[com.samu.domain.EPoint@2d5caf46 (lat: -5.580874037404866, lon: 35.94777225005756), com.samu.domain.EPoint@2163354d (lat: -5.286985080169555, lon: 35.97486383222591), com.samu.domain.EPoint@2dd124cc (lat: -5.286985080169555, lon: 35.71115171259456), com.samu.domain.EPoint@66e5987d (lat: -5.573099299909384, lon: 35.68508505352236), com.samu.domain.EPoint@2e8b3d78 (lat: -5.580874037404866, lon: 35.94777225005756)]`

EList extends from java.util.List

Comment: You can use `if(!Collections.disjoint(list1, list2)){//if one or more elements are matched} else {//No elements in common}`.

Comment: This returns false too. I just want to check if there is a single common element, I do not want to check if both lists contains exactly the same elements.

Comment: I already tried with `(!Collections.disjoint(list1, list2)` and returns false as well.

Comment: This doesn't check for exactly the same elements but checks for at least one common element. Check the values of your lists what they are containing.

Comment: You can check with this method as well: `if (!new HashSet<T>(list1).retainAll(list2).isEmpty()) {// at least one element is in common}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should override equals and hashCode of your EPoint class, right now you are cheching if the object is the same. and the object is not the same, you can see it on the addresses of the object @6ef0145 -> the are all different

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/

(sorry for the german link)
http://www.tutego.de/javabuch/Java-ist-auch-eine-Insel/10/javainsel_08_003.html#dodtp848b6b5d-0c2d-464d-ac8e-4c765d194c9e

you should compare if long and lat are the same

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was exactly that. When I overrided the equals and hashCode methods in my own EPoint java class I solved the problem  `@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof EPoint)) {
            return false;
        }
        EPoint ePoint = (EPoint) o;
        return Math.abs(Math.abs(ePoint.lat) - Math.abs(lat)) < EPSILON && Math.abs(Math.abs(ePoint.lon) - Math.abs(lon)) < EPSILON;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(lat, lon);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check for the presence of common elements, then you can make use of `retainAll(Collection<?> c)` method. Considering `listAlpha` and `listBeta` are two `List<E>`

```
List<T> commonItems = new ArrayList<>(listAlpha);
commonItems.retainAll(listBeta);
```

Now `commonItems` contains only those items that are common to `listAplha` and `listBeta`.

Answer (score 1):

The process of finding common elements is based on comparison of two or more elements. If you defined your own types (EArea, EPoint) you **must care** of equals and hashCode methods because this is a place where you write a logic of your objects commonality (more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). When you override those methods you can apply any operation provided by Collections framework or implement your own solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was exactly that. When I overrided the equals and hashCode methods in my own EPoint java class I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
if(importedAreaPoints.contains(existingAreaPoints))
```

you should have

```
if(importedAreaPoints.contains(existingArea))
```

The first is checking to see if it contains the list objec instead of the element.

The other thing to check is the `.equals(Object 0)` method, to ensure the logic is correct.

Comment: Does this solve the issue completely? If so I don't get the downvote. However in that case the question should probably be closed due to a *simple mistake not likely to help others*.

Comment: I don't get the down vote either, really people should comment when they down vote.

Comment: I am trying to find a solution using all the information that I am receiving. I will vote your answer after that. Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me as though you are trying to set a value for each element which exists in another list. In which case What I have said is correct, And `containsAll` would not work and neither would `Collections.disjoint`.